# Group where for each $d \ \big|\ |G|$ there is unique subgroup of order $d$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a finite group with $\Bbb N \ni n\ge 2$ elements. Prove that if for every divisor $d$ of $n$ there is a unique subgroup of $G$ which has $d$ elements, then $(G,\cdot)$ is a cyclic group.

**Solution :** Consider the sets $M_d=\{a\in G| \operatorname{ord} a=d\}$. Any two of these sets are disjoint and they form a partition of $G$.

We have $M_d \neq \emptyset \iff \exists$ a cyclic subgroup of $G$ of order $d$. Let's denote this subgroup by $H_d$. According to the hypothesis, $H_d$ is the unique subgroup of order $d$ of $G$.
$\implies M_d=\{a \in G \mid \langle a\rangle=H_d\}$, so $|M_d|=\phi(d)$.

We have that $n=\sum\limits_{d|n}|M_d|=\sum\limits_{d|n}\phi(d)$, which is true, so there will exist a cyclic subgroup of $G$ of order $n$. Hence, $(G,\cdot)$ is cyclic.

I came up with this solution after I read the solution of a similar problem and I tried to use the same reasoning to solve this problem. I think that the reasoning itself is sound, but I feel that there may be a few issues with my solution. I am basically assuming that none of the sets $M_d$ is empty and I don't think that is correct. Intuitively, it is , because the sets $M_d$ form a partition of $G$ and if one of them is empty, then they no longer form a partition. But I don't think that it is necessary for them to form a partition, so one of them may as well be empty and, as a result, my reasoning is flawed.

A friend suggested that I should just change $|M_d|=\phi(d)$ to $|M_d|\le \phi(d)$(which is obviously true) and then I would have that $n=\sum\limits_{d|n}|M_d| \le \sum\limits_{d|n}\phi(d)=n$, which would imply that every set $M_d$ is not empty, so $H_d$ exists and the desired conclusion is reached. To me, this seems true, but I would like to know if it really is and if there are any other better ways to repair the flaw in my solution.

Edit: Is it possible that I may not actually be assuming that $M_d$ is non-empty? What I mean is : it is true that  $M_d=\{a \in G \mid \langle a\rangle=H_d\}$(it is true because if there are to be elements of order $d$, then they will be a generator of that cyclic subgroup of order $d$).From here I get that $|M_d|=\phi(d)$, so since the sets $M_d$ form a partition I reach the equality $n=\sum\limits_{d|n}|M_d|=\sum\limits_{d|n}\phi(d)$, which is true, so from here I would get that every $M_d$ is non-empty and the conclusion would follow. Does this work?

Comment: Actually your reasoning is flawed because of a different reason: it is circular. Notice that $d = n$ itself is obviously a divisor $n$. So assuming that $M_d = M_n$ is non-empty is the same thing as assuming there is an element of order $n$ i.e. that $G$ has a single generator. But that is exactly what you are trying to prove.

Comment: @0XLR precisely, that is what I was trying to convey in the penultimate paragraph, that it is not all right to assume that $M_d$ is non-empty. Thank you for confirming that my doubts were true ! Any way to fix this? Does my friend's idea that I presented in the last paragraph work?

Comment: Another issue is with saying $|M_d|=\phi(d)$. This is true if and only if $M_d\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: I think you have pinpointed the hole in your argument: you cannot just assume that if $d|n$ then $M_d\neq\varnothing$. Note that partitions are allowed to have empty parts (to be a partition, you just need the union to be everything and any two distinct parts to be disjoint; having an empty part does not disturb either). The fix seems correct to me: either $M_d$ is empty, or else it has $\phi(d)$ elements, and you can proceed as given.

Comment: Now I get it. I would like to thank everybody for their help, I was a bit confused, but now I understand how to   fix this.

Comment: Don't you mean "$M_n$ is not empty, so $H_n$ exists" and the desired conclusion is reached"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in edit and as was said in the comments, the issue is with saying that $|M_d|=\phi(d)$ because of $M_d$'s definition, but this holds if and only if $M_d\neq\emptyset$.

However, you gave all the keys of the proof. As you said, $G$ is the disjoint union of the $M_d$s, and $|M_d|=\phi(d)$ if and only if $M_d$ is non-empty. As your friend said, if one of the $M_d$ is empty, the cardinal of the union is strictly smaller than $\sum\limits_{d|n}\phi(d)=n$, but the union is $G$ itself! Contradiction.

Comment: There is no need to argue by contradiction; you have $n=|G|=\sum |M_d| \leq \sum \phi(d) = n$, yielding equality throughout and hence $|M_d|=\phi(d)$ for each $d$, and hence $M_d\neq\varnothing$ for each $d$.

Comment: Yup you're right. Thank you!

Comment: Does the result hold if we replace "which has $d$ elements" by "of *index* $d$"?

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman The assumption with index is equivalent to the one with "$d$ elements". Indeed, let $d$ be a divisor of $n$, so that $n=dk$ with $k\in\mathbb N$. If $G$ has a subgroup of index $d$ then that subgroup has $k$ elements. Conversly, if $G$ has a subgroup with $d$ elements, then that subgroup is of index $k$.

Comment: Aah yes, so we can instead talk about the sets $M_k$, and run the argument for them.

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

And now for something totally different: your condition implies that $G$ has unique Sylow subgroups and hence is nilpotent. This reduces the problem to $p$-groups.

Now maximal subgroups of $p$-groups all have index $p$, hence have the same order. Again, the condition now implies $G$ to have a *unique* maximal subgroup $M$. Pick a $g \in G$ with $g \notin M$, and consider the subgroup $H=\langle g \rangle$. If $H \subsetneq G$, then $H \subseteq M$, contradicting the choice of $g$. So $H=G$ and $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: I am confused. Why should the condition imply that $G$ has a unique maximal subgroup? The cyclic group of order $6$ has two.

Comment: Derk, apologies for keeping you confused over the weekend. Thanks for pointing out the flaw. Repaired it.