# A finite group with a property regarding divisors of its order is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$. Prove that if for every divisor $d$ of $n$ the number of $G$'s elements whose orders divide $d$ doesn't exceed $d$, then the group is cyclic.

**My attempt:** I tried to use the same technique from here : [Group where for each $d \ \big|\ |G|$ there is unique subgroup of order $d$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3325376/group-where-for-each-d-big-g-there-is-unique-subgroup-of-order-d) .
Consider the sets $M_d=\{a\in G | \operatorname{ord}a=d$}.
We have the equivalence $M_d \neq \emptyset \iff \exists$ a cyclic subgroup $H_d$ of order $d$.
We are going to prove that if this $H_d$ exists then it is unique i.e. that there is no other cyclic subgroup of order $d$.
For $x\in G$ such that $\operatorname{ord} x=d$ we have that $\operatorname{ord}(x^r) |d$,$\forall r=\overline{0,d-1}$ and, according to the hypothesis, these are the only elements of $G$ whose orders divide $d$.
Suppose that there is another cyclic subgroup of order $d$, $H'_d \neq H_d$. Then there exists at least one more element of order $d$ which is different from $x^r$, $\forall r=\overline{0,d-1}$, contradiction.
Hence, $M_d \neq \emptyset \iff \exists$ a unique cyclic subgroup $H_d$ of order $d$.
Now, let's observe that $M_d=\{a\in G | <a>=H_d\}$, so $|M_d|\le \phi(d)$.
The sets $M_d$ form a partition of $G$, so we have that$n=|G|=\sum\limits_{d|n}|M_d| \leq \sum\limits_{d|n} \phi(d) = n$,yielding equality throughout , so every $M_d\neq \emptyset$ and the conclusion follows.
I think that this works because it is basically the same problem from the link above, but with a different condition, which also helps me to prove the uniqueness of $H_d$. The only difference is that here I have that $H_d$ is the only cyclic subgroup of order $d$, not the only subgroup of order $d$. I don't think that it affects the proof however.

Comment: It would be easier to **use** the contrapositive of the theorem in the other question:
$$\,$$
If $G$ is not cyclic, then there is some $d$ dividing $|G|$ and two distinct subgroups $H_1, H_2 \leq G$ with $|H_1| = |H_2| = d.$
$$\,$$
Then just note $|H_1\cup H_2| > d$

Comment: @BrianMoehring thank you for your nice observation ! I think that I would still have to prove the other result since it is not so well-known. Anyway, the proof I gave in my post works, right?